# Action Controller Exception Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

My create new function was working and somehow it's broken now.  Not sure why.

I'm getting this error:
[image]

And my line controller is this

```
private
 def set_space
   @space = Space.find(params[:id])
   @property = Property.find(params[:id])
 # @contract = Contract.find(params[:id])
 end
```

Comment: In which controller do you have that code?

Comment: according to errors your params do not have id in it. try to see the params.

Comment: @Athar There is `params[:id]`, but there is no space object in database having id equal to `params[:id]`

Comment: i guess you might be right. i just say so bcoz error is not showing id in it. normally when this error comes. it shows like this `Couldn't find Space with id=10`

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to get two records through one `id` in your controller method:

```
@space = Space.find(params[:id])
@property = Property.find(params[:id])
```

You should modify this code unless you are intentionally doing this.

Second, you should always check if received a valid `id` in `params[:id]` before doing `.find(params[:id])`. You can do that with:

```
@space = Space.find(params[:id]) if params[:id]
```

And if you use, `find_by_id`, it gives you `nil` if a record isn't found instead of the error message you are getting in your case.

Reason for the error you are getting is simply is that the `id` with which you are trying to access a record from db doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

I always add this block of code to the bottom of my views/layouts/application.html.erb

```
<% if Rails.env.development? %>
  <%= debug(params) %>
<% end %>
```

It should tell you what's happening with your params.

Answer (score 0):

params[:id] is nil. I would double check its being passed in the URL:

```
/route/:id
```

Or

```
/route?id=1
```

Answer (score 0):

I had set_property method on my :new action